# error : field has incomplete type in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a class based airport :D !! That contains airplanes & pilot and etc. All of these classes must be an object in a big class that called it fly, but when I create this objects in the fly class, give this error :

> error : field ' flyairplane' has incomplete type 
>   error : field ' flypilot' has incomplete type 
>     .
>     .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

/*    Prototypes   */

class date;
class Time;
class passenger;
class pilot;
class fly;
class Airplane;
class Destination;
class lane;
class Time;
class era;
class priorityQueue;





/*     class defines    */


class fly{
public:
void setflyserialNumber(string serial){
    flySerialNumber = serial;
}
void setAirPlane(Airplane a){
    flyairplane = a;
  }
  void setPilot(pilot p){
      flyPilot = p;
   }
  void setflyEra(era E){
     airplaneEra = E;
  }
  void setflyDestination(Destination D){
    airplaneDestination = D;

}
void setflyTime(Time t){
    flyTime = t;
}
void setflyDate(date D){
    flyDate = D;
}
void setPassengerNumber(int a){
passengerNumber = a ;
}
void setNumberOfWaiters(int  n){
numberOfWaiters = n ;
}
string getFlySerialNumber(){
    return flySerialNumber;
}

string getPriority(){
 stringstream stm; // crisis$fuel$flyDuration$sitnumbers$
 stm << flyairplane.getCrisisState()<< "$"<< flyairplane.getExistFuel()<< "$" << flyDuaration << "$" << flyairplane.sitNumber <<"$" ;
 return stm.str();

}

private:
string flySerialNumber;

Airplane flyairplane;
pilot flyPilot;
 /* fly contributes  */
era airplaneEra;
Destination airplaneDestination;
date flyDate;
Time flyTime;
int passengerNumber;
int numberOfWaiters;
int flyDuaration;

};

class passenger {

public :
passenger(){};
passenger(string n ,string fn , long int nc,date * bt ){
name = n ;

familyName = fn;
nationCode = nc ;
birthDate = bt;
}
void setName(string nm , string fn){
    name = nm ;
    familyName = fn ;
}
string getName(){

stringstream stm;
stm << name << " " << familyName ;
return stm.str();
}
void SetNationalCode(long int Nc) {
nationCode = Nc ;
}
long int getNationalCode(){
return nationCode;

}
private:
string name;
string familyName;
long int nationCode;
date *birthDate;
};



class pilot{
private :
string name;
string family;
int personallyCode;
date *birthDate;
date *empDate;
string Degree;
int flyTimeDuration;

public :
pilot(){};
pilot(string n , string famil , int persoalCode , date *birthD , date *empd , string deg ,int     flyTimeDur){

name = n;
family = famil;
personallyCode = persoalCode;
birthDate = birthD ;
empDate = empd ;
Degree = deg;
flyTimeDuration = flyTimeDur ;


}



};
class era{
public:
string eraname;
// location in coordinate system can define here
date flyDate;
Time flyTime;
};
class Destination{
public:
string destinationName;
// location in coordinate system can define here
date flyDate;
Time flyTime;
};
class date{

public:

int day;
int month;
int year;
date(){};
~date(){};
string dateToserial()
 {
    stringstream stm;
   stm << year << month << day;
   return stm.str();
 }

  int dateToNumber(){
  int t = day + month + year ;
  return t;

  }

   };
   class Time{

 public :
 Time(int h , int mins , int sec){
 hour = h;
 minute = mins;
 second = sec;
 }
 Time(){}
 int hour;
 int minute;
int second;
 };
  class Airplane{
 //friend class fly;
  public :
  Airplane(){    }
  Airplane(string name,date *genesis,int sitnum , int weight ,string moedl ,string produceFactor ,       int motors ,float fuelcapacity ){
   AirplaneName = name;
   genesisYear = *genesis;

    }

// void addPassenger(Passenger pass);
   string getState (){
   stringstream tstm;
   tstm << "fuelValue : "<<  fuelCapacity << " passengerNumber:"<<passangerNumbers ;
   return tstm.str();

   }
  string getAirplaneSerialnumber(){
    stringstream tempstr;
    tempstr << genesisYear.dateToserial() << weight << motorNumber << fuelCapacity;
    return tempstr.str();

   }
   void setexistfuel(float f){
   existFuel = f;

   }
   float getExistFuel(){
   return existFuel;
   }
   void setCrisisState(bool b){
   crisis = b;
   }
   bool getCrisisState(){
   return crisis;
   }
  private:
  bool crisis = false;
  string AirplaneName;
  string serialNumber;
  date genesisYear;
  int sitNumber;
  int passangerNumbers;
  int weight;
  string modelType;
  string producerFactory;
 int motorNumber;
  float fuelCapacity;
  float existFuel;

  };
class lane{
 public:
    lane();
    lane(string lsn , int cap , bool state , bool pstate)
    {
    laneSerialNumber=lsn;
    capacity = cap;
    status = state;
    portStatus = pstate;
    usedCapacity=0;
  //ctor
    }
    ~lane()
    {
  //dtor
      }
     int capacity;
    int usedCapacity;
    bool status;
    bool portStatus;
    int discharingTime;
    void setport(bool ps)
     {
         if(ps) portStatus=true; // takeOff
        else
             portStatus = false; // landing

    }
    void setStatus(bool state)
    {
        if(state) status = true;
        else
             status = false;

    }
    bool getStatus()
    {
      return status;
    }
    void setlaneSerialNumber(string lsn)
    {
    laneSerialNumber=lsn;
    }
    string getlaneSerialNumber()
    {
        return laneSerialNumber;
    }
    string toString()
    {
        stringstream stm;
        stm << laneSerialNumber << "{ "<< "Capacity : "<< capacity<< " used :"<<usedCapacity<<" _ Status : "<<status << " _ Direcion : "<< portStatus << " _ DischaringTime" <<discharingTime << endl;
        return stm.str();
    }
    string generatelaneSerialNumber()
    {
        stringstream stm;
        stm << capacity << usedCapacity << status << portStatus << discharingTime;
        laneSerialNumber = stm.str();
        return stm.str();

    }

protected:
private:
    string laneSerialNumber="";

  };
 class manager{
 // priority_queues for takeoff & landing
 // return value of the takeoff queue at time to watchtower
 // get the Objects for landing from watchtower then add it to queue by priority
 // manage priority of queue in dangerous occasions return last priority to watchtower to landing
 /*  Objects contents */
 // in every queue object there is a fly object that contain name & etc of air plane
 // & there is a number that is  combined from fuel value & Events type of landing , that created     by watchtower

 public :

 };



/*   Global functions    */

int main()
{
lane lane1("lane1",3,true,true);
Airplane plane1;

cout << "\n";
cout << lane1.generatelaneSerialNumber() << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << lane1.toString() << endl;
cout << plane1.getState();
return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you cannot use forward declarations if the object is a member variable.

Here is a post about when you can use forward declarations: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

A simple fix would be to specify all of your classes before your class Fly, but what you should do is create all of the classes in their own files (header and cpp, for declarations and definitions) and #include the necessary header files.

Answer (score 0):

Because the pilot class is declared forward.

```
Airplane flyairplane;
pilot flyPilot;


...



class pilot{
private :
string name;
string family;
int personallyCode;
date *birthDate;
date *empDate;
string Degree;
int flyTimeDuration;

public :
pilot(){};
pilot(string n , string famil , int persoalCode , date *birthD , date *empd , string deg ,int     flyTimeDur){

name = n;
family = famil;
personallyCode = persoalCode;
birthDate = birthD ;
empDate = empd ;
Degree = deg;
flyTimeDuration = flyTimeDur ;


}
```

Try not using forward declaration